# Printing space with a macro and # operator in C

Tags: c, gcc, macros

I was working with macros and wrote one like this:

```
#define STR(name) #name
```

I meant `STR()` to stringise whatever that was given to it as argument and it seemed to be working.

```
printf( STR(Hello) )
```

gave the output as expected:

```
Hello
```

So did

```
printf( STR(Hello world) );
printf( STR(String) STR(ise) );
```

which gave

```
Hello world
Stringise
```

But when I tried to use `STR()` to print *only* a space, it just didn’t work.

```
printf( STR(Hello) STR( ) STR(World) ); //There’s a space between the parenthesis of the second STR
```

Gave the output:

```
HelloWorld
```

Here the `STR( )` is ignored.

Why is this? Is there a way around it using while still sticking to macros with only a space as argument?

I was just wondering if this was possible.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I did. `printf( STR(Hello) STR(" ") STR(world) );` prints the quotes as well like `Hello" "world`.And I only want the space.

Comment: `STR( )` --> `" "`

Comment: @J...S - ah - it prints the literal quotes as well. That's  a problem `:)`

Comment: Whitespace is not anm actual parameter. Similar to `,`.

Comment: Can you give a reason for such a #define? Why do you try to make your life harder ?>

Comment: @PeterJ: Some people think their life is too easy, so they like making it more complicated.

Comment: Yes, why attempt to replace a `printf` *Format String* with macros?

Comment: @Peter You never know when such things come in handy. It is often things that we go after just out of curiosity that will help us out later.

Comment: @Olaf that's a good one :).

Comment: @J...S: A nail through your knee might come handy one day if you want to hang a piano onto it, too. That's basically what you seem to do here. Not ever problem is suitable for a hammer.

Comment: "*Is there a way around it [...]?*" no.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible for the stringification to result into a single space. The semantics of the `#` operator are detailed in [C11 6.10.3.2p2](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.10.3.2p2):

> If, in the replacement list, a parameter is immediately preceded by a `#` preprocessing token, both are replaced by a single character string literal preprocessing token that contains the spelling of the preprocessing token sequence for the corresponding argument. **Each occurrence of white space between the argument's preprocessing tokens becomes a single space character in the character string literal. White space before the first preprocessing token and after the last preprocessing token composing the argument is deleted.** *[...]* ***The character string literal corresponding to an empty argument is `""`.*** *[...]*.

Thus, as the space is not a preprocessing token, and leading and trailing space is deleted, it is impossible for the stringification operator to create a resulting string literal that just contains a single space. As you've noticed, `STR( )` would pass an empty argument to the macro, and this would be stringified into `""`; likewise

```
STR(     Hello

World
)
```

would be expanded into `"Hello World"`; i.e. each occurrence of white space would become a single space character, and the preceding and trailing whitespace would be deleted.

---

However, while it is not possible to stringify a single space, it is possible to achieve the required output. The preprocessor concatenates consecutive string literal tokens into one, so `"Hello" " " "World"` would be converted to `"Hello world"; therefore

```
printf(STR(Hello) " " STR(World));
```

would after macro expansion be expanded to

```
printf("Hello" " " "World");
```

and thereafter to

```
printf("Hello World");
```

Comment: Thew question is about macros and the `#` operator. I don't see how this answers the question.

Comment: @Olaf fixed now.

Comment: Thanks for quoting the part of standard which defines this behaviour.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala "The preprocessor concatenates consecutive string literal tokens into one" I don't think that's true.  The concatenation (phase 6) happens after the preprocessor (phase 4).